# A non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Is the following equation well known in MATHEMATICAL PHYSICS?

$$\alpha  u_{tt} - {\rm i}u_t -u_{xx}-u^3 =0.$$
Here $u = u(t,x)$ is a complex valued function and $0<\alpha <<1.$ The only well known  equation having the linear part of the above one is called the **Klein-Gordon** equation, but with non-linear term of the form $f(|u|^2)u.$

Thank you in advance for any relevant reference.

Comment: With $\alpha=0$ this is a nonlinear Schrodinger equation, as far as I remember it is used to study bose-einstein condensates.

Comment: [List of nonlinear partial differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations). The second last is similar but has different constants.